# ASP.NET attributes are only allowed in ASP.NET files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, runatserver, runat

We recently upgraded our MVC3 site to MVC4 (will then step up to 5 when we're ready) and now all of a sudden Visual Studio 2013 [Update 3] is giving tons of "errors" in the Error List, that don't seem to be breaking the build but are all over the place and making it difficult to spot real errors.

```
<table ID="myNiftyTable" runat="server" style="vertical-align:top; width:600px">
```

And similar tags like ,  etc. are all giving that error message "ASP.NET attributes are only allowed in ASP.NET files." because of the runat="server" attribute.

We had used some scripting tools to convert the old .aspx Views into Razor .cshtml so the above element formerly looked like

```
<asp:Table ID="myNiftyTable" runat="server" Width="600px" HorizontalAlign="Left">
```

Should I, can I just get rid of all those `runat="server"` attributes? The new web app seems to run OK in VS debug, but I haven't exhaustively tested all the pages & Controller methods yet so I'm not sure I want to do that, in case it breaks something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

runat="server" is only required by Webforms. It should not have been in your MVC 3 application either. You should definitely remove all references to them.

You should be able to do this with a Find & Replace across all views in your project without much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could/should get rid of them.

What happens is that `runat="server"` is rendered as an HTML attribute as if you had added a random `name="value"` attribute to your `table`. It adds and does nothing.

Having `runat="server"` everywhere will not break your website, but it serves no purpose since the ASP.NET MVC view with razor has no code-behind.

A simple replace-all will solve your problem quickly.